# C# WPF : slider going to exact position

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, slider

I'm using a slider in a WPF window and I want that when the user clicks somewhere on the track of the slider, the thumb to go to that exact position. Currently, when I click somewhere, the thumb goes towards that position, but not to **exactly** that position. How can I achieve what I want ?

Edit: An example to better explain what I want: If the thumb is at 10 and I press the mouse down near 100 , I want it to jump to 100 (without passing through other values).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you need to set `IsMoveToPointEnabled` to `True`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider.ismovetopointenabled.aspx

> **`Slider.IsMoveToPointEnabled`** Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the Thumb of a Slider moves immediately to the location of the mouse click that occurs while the mouse pointer pauses on the Slider track.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I was sure that I tried this solution, but apparently I was wrong. Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

You should handle slider thumb mouse enter event and define behvior you want.

```
var thumb = (slider1.Template.FindName("PART_Track", slider) as Track).Thumb;
thumb.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(ThumbMouseEnter);
```

Then you set position of the thumb in ThumbMouseEnter event hendler. THis will allow you to define any behavior you want.

Very similar question is asked on [social.msdn.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5fa7cbc2-c99f-4b71-b46c-f156bdf0a75a/making-the-slider-slide-with-one-click-anywhere-on-the-slider)